# Retrieve ordered list with items from SQLite database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I’m designing tables for a database.

Inside an Android app, I download - from a server - an ordered list in JSON. I insert the list and its items into a SQLite db.

The list table’s columns:

```
+ list_id
+ timestamp
```

The list item table’s column:

```
 + item_id
 + timestamp
 + list of list_ids (a list item can be in multiple lists)
```

When I retrieve the items for a list they should have the same order as when I downloaded them. What is the most efficient way to store the “list order"? One option is to let the item have a columns with a list of pair like so: list:indexInList. Appreciate advice on betters ways to do this.

Clarification: An item can occur in a list multiple times, e.g. item_ids in a list: 1,2,3,1,5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never store a list of values in a column when you might need to access individual items.

For a M:N relationship like this, you typically use a [third table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table):

```
CREATE TABLE items_in_lists (
    list_id INTEGER REFERENCES lists(list_id),
    item_id INTEGER REFERENCES items(item_id),
    PRIMARY KEY(list_id, item_id)
);
```

Once you have this table, it is the natural place to store the item's order in the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an id column with an auto-increment then add ORDER BY `id` to your query.

You can reorder your table.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ORDER BY col_name
```

Comment: Thanks. What if an item can be in a list multiple times?

Comment: It's OK if you want it to be. But then you may want a secondary column to ORDER BY.  If you do not want duplicates use a UNIQUE index to disallow duplicates.  If you want to index a column that has duplicates you just use an INDEX rather than UNIQUE Index.  You can use multiple columns in an index.